# Find middle of a list

Tags: python

How would I find the exact middle of a python list?

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5]
middle = findMiddle(aList)
print middle
```

This is just an example of a function that would be able to find the middle of any list, is this something you can do using list comprehension?

Edit: This is different than taking out the middle point because I would like to just print out the middle value, if the list is odd I would like to return both the middle values like the accepted answer. Not getting the median like the other question has asked and getting the average of the two values.

Comment: you can use list comprehension but why not just use plain old math?

Comment: What's the middle of `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: how about a[len(a)/2 ]  ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Do you want a single item that appears at the midpoint of the list? Do you want the index of that item? Do you want the interior one-third of the items in the list? Do you want something else? What is the desired output for `findMiddle([70, 51, 59, 19, 84, 91, 69, 84, 26])`? Is it `4`? Is it `84`? Is it `[19, 84, 91]`?

Comment: in this case `print middle` would print 3 so the middle item in the list

Comment: middle_index = len(alist) // 2
mid_value = alist[middle_index]

Comment: I believe a simple `aList[len(aList)//2]` should do the job.

Comment: This question is currently marked as a duplicate of another post, I believe in error. The post linked is about finding the median value of a list of numbers, but the post here is about finding the middle index of a list. These are semantically different questions, and as such I believe this question should be reopened.

Comment: @AamirJamal is ok, but if you may have empty lists, try  ```middle = aList[len(aList)//2] if aList else None```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why would you use a list comprehension? A list comprehension only knows about any one member of a list at a time, so that would be an odd approach. Instead:

```
def findMiddle(input_list):
    middle = float(len(input_list))/2
    if middle % 2 != 0:
        return input_list[int(middle - .5)]
    else:
        return (input_list[int(middle)], input_list[int(middle-1)])
```

This one should return the middle item in the list if it's an odd number list, or a tuple containing the middle two items if it's an even numbered list.

Edit:

Thinking some more about how one could do this with a list comprehension, just for fun. Came up with this:

```
[lis[i] for i in 
    range((len(lis)/2) - (1 if float(len(lis)) % 2 == 0 else 0), len(lis)/2+1)]
```

read as:

"Return an array containing the `i`th digit(s) of array `lis`, where i is/are the members of a range, which starts at `the length of lis, divided by 2, from which we then subtract either 1 if the length of the list is even, or 0 if it is odd`, and which ends at `the length of lis, divided by 2, to which we add 1`."

The start/end of range correspond to the index(es) we want to extract from `lis`, keeping in mind which arguments are inclusive/exclusive from the `range()` function in python.

If you know it's going to be an odd length list every time, you can tack on a `[0]` to the end there to get the actual single value (instead of an array containing a single value), but if it can or will be an even length list, and you want to return an array containing the two middle values OR an array of the single value, leave as is. :)

Comment: Don't shadow the `list()` built-in

Comment: What is `input_list[middle - .5]` supposed to do?

Comment: @khelwood: if we have a list with positions [0,1,2,3,4], then the len()/2 of it will return 2.5. We want index 2. So we subtract .5 to get its position.

Comment: @IanAuld, just wrote this up very quickly, primarily from javascript land where that's not a protected word. Updated appropriately.

Comment: @KyleBaker Why don't you try it and see if it works like that?

Comment: Subtracting .5 from a number will definitely give you a `float`, not an `int`, and you can't use a `float` as a list index.

Comment: thanks @khelwood. Updated. `[1,2,3,4,5].length / 2` returns 2.5 in javascript, was not expecting 2 in python. edit: aaand just realized you can't use floats as indexes. Sorry, python is still relatively new to me.

Comment: This answer would make a lot more sense if you got rid of all the floats and the casts to and from `float`.

Comment: The above logic doesn't work for all the even number list like [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Instead of middle % 2 != 0, if we change it to len(input_list) % 2 != 0 it works for all the even number of list

Answer (score 22):

Something like this would do:

```
aList = [1,2,3,4,5]
#minus 1 because the first element is index 0
middleIndex = (len(aList) - 1)/2
print middleIndex
print aList[middleIndex]
```

Comment: And if the list has four elements  then middleIndex = 1.5. Likewise, with any even length we get a fractional index. Probably we'd need to take a `floor` or a `ceil`.

Comment: I believe a simple `aList[len(aList)//2]` should do the job.

Comment: @AamirJamal you should post that as answer, it is the best one.

Comment: @AamirJamal, this is good but, like other answers, does not check that the list is empty. (IndexError: list index out of range). I would consider a complete answer to be ```lst[len(lst)//2] if lst else None```

Comment: this seems to be for python 2

Answer (score 3):

Take the length of the list, cut that in half and access whatever the list at that index point.

Comment: Ok so something like `s=len(aList)/2` then use s as the index on the list?

Comment: yes, but you need to figure out what to do with even lists.  You also need to be aware of odd length lists.  If 7, your middle would be at index 3 so you need to round down.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like

```
def findMiddle(list):
  l = len(list)
  if l/2:
    return (list[l/2-1]+list[l/2])/2.0
  else:
    return list[(l/2-1)/2]
```

Comment: What do you think `if l/2:` is doing?

Comment: I think `l` is a terrible name for a variable :-)